# Cleaning out the [wall] tag, Facebook abuse

Tags: discussion, tags, retag-request

The [wall](/questions/tagged/wall) tag contains 233 questions. Impressive at first, but about 90% of these questions are related to Facebook, and *should* be using the [facebook-wall](/questions/tagged/facebook-wall) tag instead. The rest use it as a meta tag, except for one (mentioned in comments).

At first I thought we could synonymize and merge [wall](/questions/tagged/wall) and [facebook-wall](/questions/tagged/facebook-wall) after removing the [wall](/questions/tagged/wall) tag from all the questions which use it inappropriately ([there's only 27 of them](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/wall+-facebook+-facebook-wall+-facebook-like+-facebook-graph-api+-facebook-fanpage+-facebook-connect+-fbml+-facebook-javascript-sdk+-facebook-c%23-sdk+-facebook-likebox+-facebook-apps)). This seems like the best option, but uses up a very general word "wall" specifically for Facebook. Perhaps we could just send them all to the other tag instead and then get rid of the [wall](/questions/tagged/wall) tag, so they'll at least all be on the other tag.

Comment: I haven't checked yet, but my first thought was "at least one of these must be for the compiler option `-Wall`." EDIT: Okay, here's one (possibly the only one): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4001736/what-with-the-thousands-of-warnings-in-standard-headers-in-msvc-wall

Comment: Mr. Gorbatschev, TEAR DOWN THAT WALL.

Comment: @Popular: So one out of 29? ^_^ So there's a reason to keep the main tag, we just need to get Facebook people to stop using it.

Comment: Yep. If you'd asked me to guess how many `[wall]` questions were about `-Wall` before I read this question, I wouldn've said "at least half." Definitely not "less than half of one percent."

Comment: We don't need no education....

Comment: It's now only 27 not related to Facebook. I just noticed a couple other Facebook tags that didn't have the icon in them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I disagree.  "Wall" is such a generic term that I don't believe it should be a synonym with anything for the reason you suggest.

I do, however, recommend the retagging of these questions, and burninating the [wall](/questions/tagged/wall) tag in the process (which happens shortly after you remove it from all questions that have it), making it subject to reputation requirements for creating a new tag again.