# Which tag to keep, [specificity] or [css-specificity]?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, stack-overflow, tags, retag-request

Unsurprisingly, we have two tags describing specificity in CSS rules: [specificity](/questions/tagged/specificity) and [css-specificity](/questions/tagged/css-specificity), each with just over a dozen questions.

I'm going to normalize everything to one tag, but which do I keep? The former is a bit of a dilemma as "specificity" could refer to anything, but so far all questions with it are about specificity in CSS rules. The latter is clearer and therefore safer, but based on what I just said about the former (as well as some [discussions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/117538/should-we-tag-questions-with-categorysubcategory-or-category-subcategory) about [compound tags](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/93607/should-compound-tags-be-allowed)), would it be fine to just use the former without the `css-` prefix instead?

**EDIT:** based on animuson's suggestion, I'm keeping the [specificity](/questions/tagged/specificity) tag.

Comment: Also is there a general question that *definitively* covers situations of deciding between one of [X] and [X-Y] tags where Y may not always only pertain to X in the future? All I can find are discussions that haven't gone anywhere.

Comment: I would say `specificity` suffers a noted lack of... well, *specificity*. `<rimShot/>`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I say merge them into [specificity](/questions/tagged/specificity). Specificity in itself isn't "specific" to CSS, in that **it's just the practice of being specific**. It just happens to be most commonly associated with CSS and it's statements when referred to in the programming community. Since it could, theoretically, be related to other things in programming, either now or in the future, I think not including CSS in it is a better choice.

---

Just because I was curious, a Google search for "programming specificity" brought up this:
[Introducing Generalized Specificity in Logic Programming](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/summary?doi=10.1.1.34.2727)

There's also [this JavaScript question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7853118) which is tagged with specificity, which is only indirectly related to CSS.

Comment: [specificity] would end up like [selectors] then, with multiple meanings, uses and being dependent on context :/ What you say makes more sense to me as a reason for keeping [css-specificity] instead...

Comment: I disagree, I only see the one meaning that stands out: being specific. I think the same meaning would apply no matter what other topic might arise that it could relate too. The word wasn't created to accommodate CSS, it already existed and people just used it to describe how to write CSS, by **being specific**. It's also not an extremely general word that would be picked up for random uses, like [wall](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/121227).

Comment: Oh... I was confused at first, but now I understand. Well, then.