# Can we flip the Specificity tag?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, tags, tag-synonyms

Currently [specificity](/questions/tagged/specificity) is a tag with the synonym [css-specificity](/questions/tagged/css-specificity). Considering just how many CSS-related tags are [prefixed with `css-`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/css*), can we flip this so that [css-specificity](/questions/tagged/css-specificity) is the main tag and [specificity](/questions/tagged/specificity) is a synonym of it?

Comment: What about questions like http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18430827/how-to-calculate-average-sensitivity-and-specificity-at-specified-cutoff-in-rocr ?

Comment: @Undo in that case the css-specificity tag should be a standalone thing. The specificity tag's wiki does begin "In CSS...", however, and not mention anything else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Funny, another moderator and I were just talking about this the other day. I once posted [a question of my own](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/121236/which-tag-to-keep-specificity-or-css-specificity) some time ago regarding this as well.

Since the term itself isn't necessarily associated with CSS (it just happens to be most often used to refer to CSS), and as you mentioned all the CSS subtags have the same prefix anyway, I flipped it but chose to break the synonym as well, so now both tags stand alone. Previously, whenever a question that wasn't about CSS used the tag [specificity](/questions/tagged/specificity) I would remove it and no one would bat an eye, but I think it's much simpler to stick with a prefix, really.

Comment: Except now the prefixless tag is going to show up first when people start typing "specificity," and as a result it's going to get way, way more CSS questions than it should.  :/